# Function object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I think the `Function` object is the only instance in the JavaScript. All the other `function(){...}` or `var xx=function(){...}` are the objects inherited from this `Function` object. That is the prototype based language feature. And in prototype based language there is no `Class`, and One of the advantages of it is the object can changed anytimes.such as add a method or add a property into it. So, I think we can treat `object` like a key-values collection. You can add items into it anytimes after you created it. (If I was wrong, Please correct me.)

Say you have the code:

```
        Function.test=function(){
            alert(Function.name);//"Function"  
            alert(Function.myName);//"fun"
        };
        Function.name="fun";
        Function.myName="fun";
        Function.test();
```

In the above code, all I want to do is add a `test` method to the `Function` object.
There is no error found in this code. But why `Function.name` can not be changed?

Comment: Wat way have u defined Function()?

Comment: I don't know how to answer your question... `Function` is the build-in object of javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all this property is [not standard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Name). This means that different browsers may treat it as they want. The second thing is that according to MDN it is read only.

Answer (score 1):

[A page from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Name#Description) states that the name of the Function cannot be changed because it's read only.

Comment: Hi, @Joseph the Dreamer, IE8 can change it . It is not readonly.